# How to catch exception from a class loaded with autoload in PHP?

Tags: php, exception, pdo, namespaces, autoload

The following code runs well:

```
class D {



    public static function databaseConnected( $db_server, $db_name, $db_user, $db_password )
    {
        try {
            $newDatabaseConnection = new PDO( "mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password );
            $newDatabaseConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            return $newDatabaseConnection;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            //echo $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        }
        return null;
    }

}

echo "#HEADER#<br/>";
if ($globalConn = D::databaseConnected())
    require("content.php");
else
    echo "Cannot connect to the database!<br/>";
echo "#FOOTER#<br/>";
```

But if I do the same with:

```
spl_autoload_register ( function ($class_name) {

    $class_name = str_replace ( "\\", "/", $class_name );
    require ("{$class_name}.php");
} );

use core\system\D;

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

echo "#HEADER#<br/>";
if ($globalConn = D::databaseConnected())
    require("content.php");
else
    echo "Cannot connect to the database!<br/>";
echo "#FOOTER#<br/>";
```

In the first code I get the "Cannot connect to the database!" error (exception catched), but in the second I get a Fatal error by the connection fail? (exception uncaught), How can I solve this?

(Note: the D class in the second code is located in the directory \core\system\ as is:

```
<?php

namespace core\system;

use PDO;

class D {



    public static function databaseConnected( $db_server, $db_name, $db_user, $db_password )
    {
        try {
            $newDatabaseConnection = new PDO( "mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password );
            $newDatabaseConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            return $newDatabaseConnection;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            //echo $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        }
        return null;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, because I now understand what is happening: the problem is when the script throws the `PDOException`, as you can see the `PDOException` class is not present when the `spl_autoload_register` is executed, by that reason the exception is not catched. To solve this I put this line in the file of D:

```
use PDOException;
```

The solution is like this:

```
<?php

namespace core\system;

use PDO;
use PDOException;

class D 
{
    public static function databaseConnected($db_server, $db_name, $db_user, $db_password)
    {
        try {
            $newDatabaseConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);
            $newDatabaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $newDatabaseConnection;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            //echo $e->getMessage()."<br/>";
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```